# SSL cert owner != localhost after creating SSH tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssl, x509

I use an SSH tunnel to connect to my work's mail server, then tell my mail client to connect to server "localhost" on port "1993" (the port I chose for the tunnel). I have two different Ubuntu Precise installations and each have their own partition. One of these was installed using a regular ISO downloaded from  ubuntu.com and the other was installed using a custom ISO provided by my work. When getting my email using the work-provided version of Ubuntu, everything works fine. When getting my email using the stock version of Ubuntu, everything works except I get the following error

```
Error, certificate owner does not match hostname localhost
...
Accept this certificate anyway? [no]:
```

If I enter 'y' the mail downloads fine.

My question is: where is the "localhost" coming from? I use the same config files and certificate on both installations (all symlinked from a third partition) and /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts are identical on both installations... any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you connecting to `localhost` on both versions? It could be the work image was pre-setup to use the real name and has a entry in the `hosts` file or there is a proxy running that is forwarding it though SSH for you.